# Surface integral with area restriction

Tags: area, surface-integrals

I'm stuck with the following problem.

> Evaluate the surface-integral $\int_Y xyz dS$. 
>   where $Y$ is the part of the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 =1$, that lies above the area $\{ y\leq x, x\leq 0, 0\leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 1 \}$.

I think some kind of parametric equations is necessary to solve this by hand ... but I don't know how to find the integral limits.
Please help!

Comment: The constraints restrict you to a section of the sphere above $\frac 18$ of the circle from $0$ to $45^\circ.$  Try polar / spherial coordinates  ($[0,\frac{\pi}{4}]$ will probably be more useful.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ then (recall the definition of [surface integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral))
$$I=\int_Yxyz\, dS=\int_D xy\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} \sqrt{1+z_x^2+z_y^2}\,dx dy$$
where $D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\::\; y\leq x, x≤0, 0≤ x^2 + y^2 ≤1\}$. 
Since 
$$\sqrt{1+z_x^2+z_y^2}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-x^2 -y^2}}$$
after changing to polar coordinates we get
$$I=\int_D xy\,dx dy=\int_{\rho=0}^1\int_{\theta=-3\pi/4}^{-\pi/2}\rho^2\cos\theta \sin\theta \, \rho d\theta d\rho\\
=\left[\frac{\rho^4}{4}\right]_0^1\cdot \left[\frac{\sin^2\theta}{2}\right]_{-3\pi/4}^{-\pi/2}=\frac{1}{4}\cdot (\frac{1}{2}- \frac{1}{4})= \frac{1}{16}.$$